# Backing up Isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

Some of my users have asked to have their data backed up (off the phone).  I'm using Isolated storage to store their data.  I'm wondering if there is a way that I can somehow get that information package it up and send it to a off phone location.

Is there a way to do this?  What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What type of data is it? Custom, images, music?

Comment: @DerekBeattie mostly text.  There may be an image or 2 but as of right now it is all text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if skydrive will handle backing up the type of data you have but there is an API now.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/default.aspx

Examples on GitHub:
https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK

Someone posted a question on how to backup a SQLCE database to skydrive and there didn't seem to be an API to backup random things only specific things like Pictures or Music.  I'm sure something for that could be figured out by storing some data from a browser and watching the traffic in Fiddler.

edit: side note, theres an [AWS beta](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/01/20/beta-of-aws-sdk-for-windows-phone-released.aspx) API for WP7 now.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what the data is, you can search for it like this:

[Find Existing Files and Directories in Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd5e2z84.aspx)

Then you can use SkyDrive to save users data onto it.

You can use the [Live SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28195).